# PHP image resizing - Opinions wanted

Tags: php, image-processing, resize, image-resizing

I have been looking around and would like to know what everyone uses to resize images in case I am missing out.

I am using php imageGD library imagejpeg() ect.

I have continually updated my class to try and "Solve" this one situation:

If an image a user uploads is say 469x358 and the display end picture needs to be or is designed to fit within a 120x80 box for instance. If i resize based upon width the resulting resized image will be 120x92, i could just then fix the height but that will pixelate or squash the image, i could also crop the end off with either imageGD or css overflow hidden.

I have had a quick look and seen that there are algorithms(bicubic ect) that you can use to shrink an image which sharpens it so it doesnt look squashed, which is the continual effect i seem to get with imageGD. Has anyone used this algorithm?

I have also seen ImageMagick has anyone used this software? Does it shrink an image better?

I am currently cropping the end off with overflow hidden, but is there a better way?

Comment: [Image Scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling) gives a rough overview about the various methods (algorithm) - at least the most common ones. What's better depends on what you would like to achieve.

Comment: I think after about 5 minutes reading the ImageMagick documentation it is the way to go I am shocked that I have never actually heard or used it before. It has the feature that I want http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#resize it will only shrink larger images and resizes to fit best into a certain dimension specified. Is this what everyone else uses?

Comment: that always depends. If it fits for you, use it. I know that many are confident with imagemagick, so just go ahead. I know there is a new version that has better support for memory and processors, but that's merely a note in the margin

Comment: ImageMagick is quite good, yes. I believe it can produce higher quality results than GD.... but it's confusing. I like that it has unsharp mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If an image a user uploads is say
>   469x358 and the display end picture
>   needs to be or is designed to fit
>   within a 120x80 box for instance. If i
>   resize based upon width the resulting
>   resized image will be 120x92, i could
>   just then fix the height but that will
>   pixelate or squash the image, i could
>   also crop the end off with either
>   imageGD or css overflow hidden.

If your image was 358x469 (portrait) and you want to resize it to 120x80 so that the image does not look distorted, here is the math:

```
358/469 = width/80 => width = 358*80/469 = 61px (approx)
```

We had a taller image we'll use maximum height and constrained width. A desired width of 120px means the image is stretched horizontally; with a better algorithm you can only achieve smoothness but you cannot make a squashed/stretched image look normal with a better algorithm.

If fitting is required, I suggest that you crop-to-fit of resize-to-fit. You can do this on the server side via GD library/ImageMagick or on the client side using CSS background positioning. If you're using GD, cropping is as simple as resizing the image with negative offsets (somewhat similar to CSS background positioning with negative background-position).

## Edit 1

If it is a question of whether to use GD or IM, I'd suggest IM. I am not sure about the quality of output but as far as performance is concerned, IM will outperform GD, specially when you are dealing with high resolution images. In case you prefer GD, the GD library function `imagecopyresampled` will give you better results compared to `imagecopyresized` but higher CPU and/or memory usage.

## Edit 2

I forgot to mention, I stopped using GD long time ago and switched to [phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/). Takes care of most of the chores. Internally it uses GD and/or IM -- built-in intelligence lets it select the best available method for a given operation.

Answer (score 0):

A few points that might help you decide.

- The resampled output from ImageMagick and gd2 were largely similar. I'm not sure what sort of resampling gd2 performs, and I'm fairly certain that ImageMagick uses bicubic interpolation, but either way, for most cases, bicubic and bilinear resampling generate outputs that are virtually identical while downsizing. Upscaling a small image is where bicubic interpolation really stands apart. (Even so, there are some pathological cases where the difference between bicubic and bilinear interpolation might be striking -- check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing)
- I haven't had much chance to use the ImageMagick module in PHP, though the CLI version was blazing fast for resampling images. Assuming the `Imagick` module is similarly fast, you should see quick performance. However, in the case of gd2, speed has been a bit of an issue -- I've frequently used it for generating 50-odd thumbnails per page, and the lag is noticeable.
- gd2 is a part of most PHP installations, and the API is fairly simple to use. `Imagick` seems to be a PECL extension. Depending on your hosting provider, that may or may not be an issue.

That said, let me point out that it's **almost always** a better idea to cache resized images -- especially if you are sure that the same image will be resized frequently. For instance, if you were creating, say, some online shop and wanted to display image thumbnails, it'd particularly suck if you ran the same set of images through the resizer again and again. OTOH for applications where the images are more variable, on-the-fly resizing might be the better option.

Comment: I have gone for ImageMagick, its actually easier a lot less code to write as its linux commands. If your ok with linux commands I would go with ImageMagick it has made a massive difference to the appearance of my sites as I now specify fit inside 120x80 box and I get an optimized image back that fits in it, no more overflow hidden!

Comment: Nonetheless, consider the benefits offered by caching the resized images if that is relevant to your case.